# xsl fill table by column

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to do something like that

this is my xml:

```
<TSRslt>
<TSExpectedResult Expected = "result : 42.7400131226"></TSExpectedResult>
<TSActual Actual = "result :  42.7400131226" Result = "0"></TSActual>
</TSRslt>
<TSRslt>
<TSExpectedResult Expected = "result :xyz"></TSExpectedResult>
<TSActual Actual = "result :  xyz" Result = "1"></TSActual>
</TSRslt>
```

this is my stylesheet xsl:

```
<TABLE id="table2" class="tl2" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2" width="100%">
        <TR><TH noWrap = "noWrap" class="br">Expected</TH>
            <TH noWrap = "noWrap" class="br">Actual</TH>
        </TR>
        <TR>

                <xsl:for-each select="TSRslt">
                    <TR><TD class="br2" width="50%"><xsl:for-each select="TSExpectedResult"><xsl:value-of select="@Expected" /></xsl:for-each></TD>
                    <TD class="br2" width="50%"><xsl:for-each select="TSActual">
                    <xsl:if test="@Result = '0'">
                        <FONT COLOR = "#000000">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Actual" />
                        </FONT>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="@Result = '1'">
                        <FONT COLOR = "#000000">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Actual" />
                        </FONT>
                    </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each></TD>
                    </TR>
                </xsl:for-each>



        </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

however my xml is not like that. Its tags' orders are like:

```
<TSExpectedResult Expected = "result : -32.60900"></TSExpectedResult>
<TSExpectedResult Expected = "result : -32.60900"></TSExpectedResult>
<TSActual Actual = "result :  -32.60900" Result = "0"></TSActual>
<TSActual Actual = "result :  -32.60900" Result = "0"></TSActual>
```

I have too many xml files, therefore I cannot change all tags' orders. how can I fill a table with this order:

```
 Expected Results     Actual REsults
  1                    4
  2                    5
  3                    6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you like to access the TSActual  entry wiht the same position as the TSExpectedResult  entry.

Therefor have a for-each loop over TSExpectedResult  and to access the TSActual  entry
put the current position into a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
```

and use this to access the TSActual  entry:

```
 select="../TSActual[position() = $pos]"
```

Also in the following example I removed not needed loos and use applay template.

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match ="TSActual" mode="td">
        <FONT COLOR = "#xxxx">
            <xsl:attribute name="COLOR" >
                <xsl:if test="@Result = '0'">#000001</xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@Result = '1'">#000002</xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Actual" />
        </FONT>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <TABLE id="table2" class="tl2" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2" width="100%">
            <TR>
                <TH noWrap = "noWrap" class="br">Expected</TH>
                <TH noWrap = "noWrap" class="br">Actual</TH>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <xsl:for-each select="TSExpectedResult">
                    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                    <TR>
                        <TD class="br2" width="50%">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Expected" />
                        </TD>
                        <TD class="br2" width="50%">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="../TSActual[position() = $pos]" mode="td" />
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but there is an error. The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Keyword xsl:template may not be used here.

Comment: I have a part that <xsl:template match="ExternalTestResults"> may be the error appears for this.

Comment: I wonder that cant I do something like that

<xsl:template match="ExternalTestResults"><xsl:template match ="TSActual" mode="td">?

Comment: You can't have a `xsl:template` inside of another `xsl:template`. You should only put the content of my `template match="/*"` into your  `match="ExternalTestResults"` template.

Comment: you mean I should change the match="ExternalTestResults" to match="/*"?
But I have another table which includes this table:/

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this issuse except using xsl:template?

Comment: I am sorry if I understand you wrong. I delete the part <xsl:template match="/*"> in your code. and I change my code extenalresults to /*. And then it seems work, however actual result is not appear.

Comment: This depends on the xml part (around your data), which you did not show. The template with the table needs to match the node which is parent to TSExpectedResult (ExternalTestResults?) But also your root template (if any) needs to apply this direct or indirect. The solution above should work if there is only one xml node around your  data.

Comment: Can you help me with this part. 
<xsl:apply-templates select="TSActual[position() = $pos]" mode="td" />

Comment: Did you add the `template match ="TSActual" mode="td"`? And TSActual belong to the same parent as TSExpectedResult?

Comment: they belong to same parent. but ı dont understand where should I add template match ="TSActual" mode="td" . because ı cannot change the part of <xsl:template match="ExternalTestResults"> which is being the top of my code..

Comment: You can have as many templates as you like as child of `xsl:stylesheet` (as in the above solution)